# Getting current time return fine while I'm connected to WIFI, api response time is getting wrong if I connected to LTE

Tags: php, android, api, retrofit

I'm have written one api call to get current_server_time. Its working good if I connect my mobile to wifi and make a call, tha problem is when I switch to my Mobile data the response is getting struck at first call.

if I'm using WIFI the response of 1st call

`{"status":true,"currenttime":"2018-10-16 14:00:05"}`

2nd call

```
{"status":true,"currenttime":"2018-10-16 14:00:07"}
```

but if I'm using mobile data the response of 1st call

```
{"status":true,"currenttime":"2018-10-16 14:00:05"}
```

2nd call

```
{"status":true,"currenttime":"2018-10-16 14:00:05"}
```

3rd call

```
{"status":true,"currenttime":"2018-10-16 14:00:05"}
```

4th call

```
{"status":true,"currenttime":"2018-10-16 14:00:05"}
```

My php code is

```
public function actionCurrent_time()
 {

   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
   $date       = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

   $result1 = array();

   $result1['status'] = true;
   $result1['currenttime'] = $date;

   echo $string = 
   str_replace('\"','',str_replace("\/","/",json_encode($result1)));

  }
```

Comment: What url are you using to make the call. Code is always useful in an SO question

Comment: http://13.126.67.195/backend/web/index.php/site/current_time  this is the URL I'm calling and its GET method

Comment: may be the library you are using to make call is returning cached response

Comment: Your provider might be caching the response, so try with something like 13.126.67.195/backend/web/index.php/site/current_time?RANDOM_NUMBER - where RANDOM_NUMBER is something that you change with every call

Comment: I'll try and let you know

Comment: Sorry It's not working, Same issue..I'll send my php code for ref

Comment: Please see my updated question